# How to disable wifi usage on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

On a laptop, we currently use LAN(RJ45) connection to access internet.
But from time to time, on startup, the laptop "catch" an unsecured wifi hotspot from one of my neighbors,
so we would like windows 7 to NOT choose any wifi network : how this can be done ?

Answer (score 2):

Windows shouldn't normally connect to any wireless networks. You must have connected to them at an earlier date and it has remembered this. To stop this:

1. Open the network and sharing centre
2. Click manage wireless networks from the menu on the right
3. `Right click -> remove` the networks you don't want to connect to

Answer (score 1):

You can disable wireless service.

Right-click on My Computer, services. Find Wireless Zero Configuration service and Stop it (right-click). To avoid starting it up at next boot, change it's startup type from Automatic to Manual.

Once you do need Wireless, just start service (right-click) again.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to disable the wifi port instead? Since most laptops have a Fn key for that?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you're already in the Network and Sharing Center, go to Change adapter settings, right-click the wireless connection, and click Disable. A UAC prompt is triggered. To re-enable, simply go back, and click Enable instead of Disable. Practically fool-proof way of disabling wireless, on any Windows OS. (Well, unless you're so old that the OS doesn't support wireless, but that's a different story).

Once again:

```
1) Open the Network and Sharing Center.
2) Click "Change adapter settings" in the left-hand panel of sorts.
3) Right-click "Wireless Network Connection" and click "Disable".
4) Click "Yes" to the UAC prompt, or enter an administrator password.
```

To re-enable:

```
1) Open the Network and Sharing Center.
2) Click "Change adapter settings" in the left-hand panel.
3) Right-click "Wireless Network Connection" and click "Enable".
4) Click "Yes" to the UAC prompt, or enter an administrator password.
```